# how to display image in rdlc from database byte array in wpf c#

Tags: rdlc

```
SignatureImage =(byte[])dr["SignImage"];
SignatureImage1 = Encoding.Default.GetString(SignatureImage);

bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.White);
char div = '^';
string[] signature_divide = SignatureImage1.Split(div);
string x;
string y;
string x_y;
int mt30Flag = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < signature_divide.Length - 1; i++) {
    try
    {

        x_y = signature_divide[i];
        int pos = signature_divide[i].IndexOf(",");
        x = x_y.Substring(0, pos);

        y = x_y.Substring(pos + 1);

        if (Int32.Parse(y) == 65535)
        {
        mt30Flag = 1;
        }


        if (Int32.Parse(x) <= 480 && Int32.Parse(y) <= 320)
        {
        bmp.SetPixel(Int32.Parse(x), Int32.Parse(y), System.Drawing.Color.Black);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {

    }

} 
objset.tbl_Image.Merge(tempimage);
```

**no error found and not any exception ** But image not displaying in rdlc.

In Above code I Have Converted my byte type Data into bitmap and pass to rdlc datasource .
Please help me to display image in rdlc from database byte array.**ASAP**

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319071/how-to-show-image-from-byte-array-in-microsoft-report

Answer (score 0):

you need to set Image's property Datasource to Database. And use the byte[] field.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSAnY.png)